# Is it possible for me to upgrade from 16.04 to just 18.04, not going to 19.04?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 19.04

I am currently running a chroot on my chromebook in version 16.04.  I want to perform an upgrade (ideally via the terminal) that upgrades to just 18.04, not to 19.04.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by default upgrades to the next LTS, which is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  To upgrade to 19.04, you'd have to go to 18.04, then 18.10, then 19.04 (unless you re-installed or forced a irregular/untested upgrade-path)  `do-release-upgrade` is the command I'd use  (backup, ensure system is upgraded first, reboot if necessary then `do-release-upgrade`)

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for answering.